# regex matching char only if a specific char appeared before (conditional regex)

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

developing a mobile (israeli) phone number regex. currently I have

```
re.compile(r'^[\(]?0?(5[023456789])\)?(\-)?\d{7}$')
```

which catches most use cases. the problem is matching the second parenthesis only if a first one parenthesis appears.

so (055)-5555555 or (055)5555555 or 0555555555 would match
but: 055)-5555555 wouldn't.
I know I can use 2 regex to test for the condition (if the first one matches test for the other condition) but that doesn't seem like a smart solution.

I guess I need something like a regex lookaround but not sure how to use it, or that I understand the concept correctly

**Edit: explaining the logic**

the area code: should start with 5 and then a single digit number (from a specific list), with an option zero before. also possible that would be inside a parenthesis.
then an optional hyphen
and 7 digits

**Clarfication:** I need to match both parenthesis only if the other one exists, that true also for the first one not only for the second one, missed that point

Comment: No need to put the opening parenthesis in a character group. `\(?` suffices.

Comment: There's a very good explanation at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Could you list the logic requirements instead of requiring us having to dissect your regex?

Comment: `h = re.compile(r'^[\(]{0,1}0?(5[023456789])\)?(\-)?\d{7}$')`

Comment: The look around looks for a repeated character, not a matching one. You should capture the brackets and test that you have 0 or 2.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan doesn't work, matched '055)6666666' that shouldn't be matched since supposed to match the second parenthsis only if the first one exists and the otherway around

Comment: @alonisser actually working i tested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you must capture the opening parenthesis and then use a [conditional pattern](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.conditional.php) (*I know the link is to php.net but I find it useful when referencing regexes, it also includes an example which exactly matches your case*) that will only be applied if the first opening parenthesis is matched.

The pattern..

```
^(\()?0?(5[02-9])(?(1)\))-?(\d{7})$
```

Will **match**:

```
(055)-5555555
(055)5555555 
0555555555
```

but **not**:

```
055)-5555555
```

### Captured groups

1. The opening parenthesis (empty if not found)
2. Area code (eg. 55)
3. The phone number (eg. 5555555)

### How it works

The part `(\()?` matches the opening parenthesis. It's optional.

The part `(?(1)\))` checks if the first captured group (in our case the opening parenthesis) has a match, if **YES** then the string **must** also match the closing parenthesis.

If no opening parenthesis has been found, the condition is effectively ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `(?(id/name)yes-pattern|no-pattern)` syntax to match the closing parenthesis only if the opening parethesis matched:

```
re.compile(r'^(\()?0?(5[023456789])(?(1)\))-?\d{7}$')
```

The `(?(1)\))` part matches `\)` if there is a group 1 (the `|` no pattern is optional).

Demo:

```
>>> phone.search('(055)-5555555')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x101e18a48>
>>> phone.search('055)-5555555') is None
True
```

Comment: Doesn't work.. this matches '055)6666666' that shouldn't be matched

Comment: Replace `(?(0)\)|)` with `(?(1)\))`: the first captured group is what you need, and the `|` and empty pattern is optional.

Comment: @alonisser: Yeah, silly mistake by testing for the 0 pattern (the whole match).